# Jersey update user on front-end while a big request is running

Tags: java, jersey, updates

Currently I'm working on a single page application with java/jersey running as my back-end. But at the moment I have some requests that take a while (over 10 seconds). I was wondering if its possible to send updates back to the client with jersey?

I wanna use like a status bar but I have no clue how far the request is without updates from the back-end.

I couldn't find anything about this topic searching on google/stackoverflow. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

Comment: hint: `websocket` as one option...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use websockets there are a few approaches you can take.

Provide API to client that takes `clientId` and optionally `processId` and gives status of the process running on server.

Then client can have Javascript to asynchronously call this API and update progress bar.

In addition you can have server side Jersey resource start long running process asynchronously and immediately return response with estimated time and `processId`.

Comment: How should I approach this? Some example code would be nice.

Comment: This would require stateful server and sticky sessions in case of any fronting / load-balancing services